# Comparing cell value 450-500 to another cell of value 475 in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I wanted to compare the price range column which will have prices range like 450-500 to another cell value 703.
In this image you can see I need to find column `D` value (which is the price range) to Column `F` which will be the current market price (CMP) which will change every day.
If it falls under the price range I need that cell to be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following formula having an `IF` statement:

```
=(IFERROR(MAX(SPLIT(D3,"-")),0))>F3
```

[image: cond. formatting]

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.